Characterize a specific measurable space
This exercise is from J.F Le Gall GTM294, Measure theory, probability and stochastic processes.
Exercise 4.8
(1) Let $f$ and $g$ be two nonnegative measurable functions on a measure space $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $fg\ge 1$. Prove that
$$
\int f\,d\mu \int g\,d\mu \ge \mu(E)^2
$$
(2) Characterize the measure space $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ on which there exists a measurable function $f>0$ such that both $f$ and $1/f$ are integrable.

Here is my solution: for the first question, note that $f g\ge 1$ implies $f^{1/2}g^{1/2}\ge 1$. Write
$$
\mu(E)^2 = (\int \mathbf{1}_{E}\,d\mu)^2\le (\int f^{1/2}g^{1/2}\,d\mu)^2 \le \int f\,d\mu \int g\,d\mu 
$$
the last less than is by Holder inequality. But I don't know how to solve the second problem. From the first question we can see that $f$ and $1/f$ satisfy the condition and
$$
||f||_1\cdot||\frac{1}{f}||_1\ge \mu(E)^2
$$
I can only get if one of them is integrable with finite measure, another is also integrable, but how to "characterize" this measure space?

The phrasing with "measure space" being singular is a bit unusual, but I guess the solution is that such a function exists if and only if $\mu(E)<\infty$.

by the way, the first question is also in Big Rudin.

$f+\frac 1  f \ge 2$ so integrability of $f$ and $\frac  1 f$ implies integrability of the constant $2$ which means $\mu (E) <\infty$. Conversely, if $\mu (E)<\infty$ then we can take $f\equiv 1$.

so, a finite measure characterize this space
